# Do light fixtures have to be CSA approved in NB Canada?

Tags: electrical, lighting

Will electricians install light fixtures that are “UL and “ETL” listed in NB Canada or Do light fixtures have to be CSA approved in NB Canada?

Comment: Is there a small "C" before the UL or ETL mark?

Comment: Yes there is a small “c” before

Answer (score 1):

NEW BRUNSWICK REGULATION 84-165-3(1)No person shall install, attempt to dispose of, dispose of or use any electrical equipment, electrical fixtures, appliances and their components which are not certified by the Canadian Standards Association, the Underwriters’ Laboratories of Canada or any other recognized testing laboratory acceptable to the Chief Electrical Inspector.

Each testing lab has specific marks for Canada, if [ULC](https://marks.ul.com/about/ul-listing-and-classification-marks/appearance-and-significance/marks-for-north-america/) or [ETLC](https://led-light-world.ca/pages/etl-of-canada) approved there is a small c located outside the circle around the 8:00 position.